# Is it possible to 'inject' reference to a JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, openapi

Considering I need to refer to a json with the following format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "ObjectA"
    }
}
```

When I write JSON schema (or more specifically, schema object of OpenAPI Specification v3.0.3) for this json request, I write

```yaml
components:
    schemas:
        Data:
            type: object
            required:
                - data
            properties:
                data:
                    $ref: '#components/schemas/ObjectA'
        ObjectA:
            type: object
            properties:
                type:
                    type: string
        ObjectB:
            type: object
            properties:
                type:
                    type: string
                some_properties:
                    type: string
```

... and I refer to it using `$ref: '#components/schemas/Data'`.

However now there is the other json to deal with, which is very similar to the one above except that the object in `data` property is not of type `ObjectA`, it is `ObjectB` instead.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "ObjectB",
        "some_properties": "which is different from ObjectA"
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to reuse the schemas for `Data` above without creating a new schema (so it is like injecting `#components/schemas/ObjectA` or `#components/schemas/ObjectB` into Data whenever needed)?

I have considered using `oneOf` but it does not fit since only a specific object is valid for a specific API endpoint (even though all are under the data property) instead of any one of the available objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simple example, it seems unnecessary to re-use the simple `Data` definition. However, assuming your actual structure is more complex you could combine the general attributes with the specific ones via `allOf`, e.g.

```yaml
components:
    schemas:
        BaseData:
            type: object
            required:
                - data
            properties:
                data:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        type:
                            type: string
                    required:
                        - type
        DataA:
            allOf:
                - $ref: '#components/schemas/BaseData'
                - type: object
                  properties: 
                      data:
                          $ref: '#components/schemas/ObjectA'
        DataB:
            allOf:
                - $ref: '#components/schemas/BaseData'
                - type: object
                  properties: 
                      data:
                          $ref: '#components/schemas/ObjectB'
        ObjectA:
            type: object
            properties:
                type:
                    const: ObjectA
        ObjectB:
            type: object
            properties:
                type:
                    const: ObjectB
                some_properties:
                    type: string
                required:
                    - some_properties
```

Depending on the actual complexity, the schema might be easier to read/maintain if the shared parts are simply duplicated.

Comment: It's worth noting that JSON Schema in OAS 3.0.3 is not actual JSON Schema. If you want to do this in JSON Schema on its own, you will need to use `definitions`.